# How does test-ng picks up test methods for execution from test-ng suite file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Does test-ng internally uses Java reflection concept to pick test methods from test-ng suite file?

Like, in testng.xml file we'll be mentioning the class name. Then, test methods in that particular class will be executed by test-ng.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java This is the entry point for testNg with the main method...